# Angular2 RC6 Feature Flags

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been working a lot with angualar2 (now RC6) with a seed (https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed)

And I want to know if there are some best practices or alredy developed modules (or services) for doing Feature flags (i.e.: enabling/disabling features for a given country, language or some condition)

Does anyone have a clue for this? I was thinking in shared service and a json file with the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the track, I created my own module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-feature-flag

If someone uses it, please let me know and I will help with the integration or I will add more features